# Is it possible to add a divider in between the navigation items of a navigation folder

Tags: navigation

I have another site with around 50 navigation items and users are finding it hard to find a particular navigation items since all of them are important and thus cannot hide them.

Is there a way to add divider(s) in between navigation items so that it look more neater?

Of course, I can simply put them into folder but I was thinking if I also have 50 navigation folders, divider will definitely come in quite handy.

Answer (score 3):

You can use below properties of Menu to set divider(separator) as per your need:

[StaticBottomSeparatorImageUrl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.menu.staticbottomseparatorimageurl%28v=VS.90%29.aspx)

[StaticTopSeparatorImageUrl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.menu.statictopseparatorimageurl%28v=VS.90%29.aspx)

[DynamicBottomSeparatorImageUrl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.menu.dynamicbottomseparatorimageurl.aspx)

[DynamicTopSeparatorImageUrl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.menu.dynamictopseparatorimageurl.aspx)

If you want to group a set of items with separator, you can have a code behind and set the separator accordingly.